# Suddenly beacon is not detected anymore (neither in iOS nor in Android)

Tags: android, ios, detection, gimbal

The beacons (QUALCOMM/Gimbal beacons) worked fine unitl yesterday. Since yesterday I have not been receiving any signal from those beacons neither in my app nor in another Android App "Bluetooth LE Scanner" (LG G2 mini) nor in another iPhone app "Beacon Scanner" (iPhone 5).

I created a test configuration in my https://manager.gimbal.com account. When trying to flash the concerned iBeacon it still dosn't get detected.

Battarystate of beacons is OK.

Anybody any ideas or similar experiences?

Comment: Are you sure the battery didn't die?

Answer (score -1):

It is solved - Thank you Ian.

Maybe the problem were the batteries - I replaced all batteries and aditionally configured a brand new Gimbal-beacon in the Gimbal-manager.
But how likely is it that the batterie-state of 5 Gimbal-beacons went critically within such a short time (more or less "at once").
Nevertheless - beacons are up and running again.

**Note1:** After the beacons went offline yesterday I started the development-iPhone5 (it's not used regularly) and it said:
"Beacon Mgr has been using your location in the background. Do you want to continue allowing this? This is required in order to see your Gimbal beacons." 
I clicked "Continue" in this popup.

**Note2:** I contacted the Gimbal-support from directly out of the https://manager.gimbal.com - Platform.

Maybe this also had some influence.